# C#: how to copy a large array of structs efficiently?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Any faster way of copying arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099604/c-any-faster-way-of-copying-arrays)

I have an array of structs like this:

```
struct S
{
    public long A;
    public long B;
}

...
S[] s1 = new S[1000000];
...
S[] = new S[s1.Length];
// Need to create a copy here.
```

I can use unsafe mode and copy the source array of structs to a byte array and then from byte array to destination array of structs. But that means I will have to allocate a huge intermediate byte array. Is there a way to avoid this? Is it possible to somehow represent a destination array as a byte array and copy directly there?

```
unsafe
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(s0[0]) * s0.Length;
    byte[] tmp = new byte[size];
    fixed (var tmpSrc = &s0[0])
    {
        IntPtr src = (IntPtr)tmpSrc;
        Marchal.Copy(tmpSrc, 0, tmp, 0, size);
    }

    // The same way copy to destination s1 array...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just doing a normal array copy and done performance testing on it?  Verify that the normal route isn't too slow before optimizing.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Removed my comment. Actually using Buffer.BlockCopy may be the to go. Nonetheless the question is still valid. Maybe not from practical point of view :)

Comment: Looks like reasonable signpost to the duplicate... Consider not deleting.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open as this is specifically about arrays of *structs*, as such the question that was linked to doesn't address this. E.g. BlockCopy is for arrays of primitive types only, not structs.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `Buffer.BlockCopy`, it copies bytes[] to byte[] and not logical elements in array.

But this is really dependent on case to case.

Please test your code with `Array.Copy` first and see.