# Create a copy of integer array

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Any faster way of copying arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099604/c-any-faster-way-of-copying-arrays)

I have an integer array

```
int[] a;
```

I want to assign a copy of it(not reference) to

```
int[] b;
```

what is the easier way to do it?

Answer (score 31):

You can use the native `Clone` method, try something like this:

```
int[] b = (int[])a.Clone();
```

Other options are, using linq:

```
using System.Linq;

// code ...
int[] b = a.ToArray();
```

And copying the array

```
int[] b = new int[a.Length];
a.CopyTo(b, 0);
```

Answer (score 5):

I think simplest way would be

```
int[] b = a.ToArray();
```

Comment: This requires `using System.Linq;` before it works.

Comment: SUPER late but I am pretty sure Linqs ToArray checks the underlying type and, if it is an array, just returns immediately.

Comment: @Marie It most certainly cannot return immediately, as LINQ methods like `ToList` and `ToArray` return a new collection. That is very important when modifying the resulting collection: the original collection is not modified. LINQ does optimize the `ToArray` implementation for types that implement `ICollection<T>`, as their `Count` property lets it create an array of the correct size immediately.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copyto.aspx) method.

```
int[] a = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] b = new int[3];
a.CopyTo(b,0);
```