# Fastest method for copying a string array in C# - direct assigning or using Copy(), CopyTo() or Clone()

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, performance-testing

I tried to find out which is the fastest method for copying a string array by using this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch copy = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch copyTo = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch direct = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch clone = new Stopwatch();

        string[] animals = new string[1000];
        animals[0] = "dog";
        animals[1] = "cat";
        animals[2] = "mouse";
        animals[3] = "sheep";
        for (int i = 4; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            animals[i] = "animal";
        }

        copy.Start();
        string[] copyAnimals = new string[animals.Length];
        Array.Copy(animals, copyAnimals, animals.Length);
        copy.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Copy: " + copy.Elapsed);

        copyTo.Start();
        string[] copyToAnimals = new string[animals.Length];
        animals.CopyTo(copyToAnimals, 0);
        copyTo.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Copy to: " + copyTo.Elapsed);

        direct.Start();
        string[] directAnimals = new string[animals.Length];
        directAnimals = animals;
        direct.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Directly: " + direct.Elapsed);

        clone.Start();
        string[] cloneAnimals = (string[])animals.Clone();
        clone.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Clone: " + clone.Elapsed);

    }
```

In most cases the ranking by fastest is: CopyTo(), Clone(), Directly, Copy(), however it is not absolutely consistent. What is your experience? Which one do you use the most and why?

Comment: you're doing different things and this is not a question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099604/c-any-faster-way-of-copying-arrays

Comment: Would you please clarify?

Comment: Direct assign is not a copy indeed. All other methods are similiar. Also you missed old good for/froeach loop. Finally, if you run this program one time or too, it's a mistake in measurement.

Comment: Read the FAQ, escpecially this part: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: What is the direct assing? Why is this not copying?

Comment: `string[] directAnimals = new string[animals.Length]; directAnimals = animals;` You just create another reference to animals array. Now you can modify animals and will see that directAnimals also modified. This is not a copy.

Comment: asigning ist this `array1 = array2` but this is not copying. It's referencing.

Comment: But after all, all other methods perform shallow copying, so that array2 will reference the objects of array1. Isn't this the same?

Comment: No, not the same. In other methods, if you assign array[0] = null, it will not affect array2[0], in direct assignment it will.

Comment: The code that you are testing is doing way too little work to measure the performance time reliably, which also your results show. Direct assignment should always be about 1000 times faster than copying the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.CopyTo` is just a wrapper around `Array.Copy`. That is, `CopyTo` does essentially this:

```
void CopyTo(Array dest, int length)
{
    Array.Copy(this, dest, length);
}
```

So `Copy` will be *slightly* faster than `CopyTo` (one less indirection).

Your direct copy doesn't actually copy the array. It just copies the reference. That is, given this code:

```
    string[] directAnimals = new string[animals.Length];
    directAnimals = animals;
```

If you then write `animals[0] = "Penguin";`, then `directAnimals[0]` will also contain the value `"Penguin"`.

I suspect that `Clone` will be the same as `Array.Copy`. All it does it allocate a new array and copy the values to it.

Some notes on timing:

Your tests are doing far too little work to time accurately. If you want meaningful results, you'll have to execute each test many times. Something like:

```
copyTo.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    string[] copyToAnimals = new string[animals.Length];
    animals.CopyTo(copyToAnimals, 0);
}
copyTo.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Copy to: " + copyTo.Elapsed);
```

For such small arrays, 1,000 times might not even be enough. You might need a million just to see if there's any meaningful difference.

Also, your results will be meaningless if you run these tests in the debugger. Be sure to compile in release mode and run with the debugger detached. Either execute from the command line, or use Ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you! One question though: you say "So CopyTo will be slightly faster (one less indirection)." Shouldn't Copy() be faster than CopyTo(), as the latter redirects to the former, so that we have "one less indirection" in the case of Copy(), not CopyTo()?

Comment: @AlexBG: You were right. I corrected my post.