# Fastest way to move a chunk of bytes from one position in a byte array to another within the same array

Tags: c#

So the question is pretty straight forward. I have a byte array and I want to move a chunk of those bytes from index `i` to index `i - delta`.

Currently I'm using `Array.Copy` but I'm worried that it might have trouble if the source and destination is the same. Also, `Array.Copy` deals with any array and since I have this specific type I was wondering if there exists a faster solution.

Comment: _"Array.Copy deals with any array and since I have this specific type I was wondering if there exists a faster solution"_ What makes your array so _specific_?

Comment: I was refering to "Copies a range of elements in one Array to another Array and performs type casting and boxing as required."
I assumed that since I have an array of bytes (as far as I know the most low level data storage you can get in C#) there might be a way to do it faster using some hardware magic (since hardware doesn't have to deal with any casting or boxing)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any faster way of copying arrays in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099604/any-faster-way-of-copying-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

> If sourceArray and destinationArray overlap, this method behaves as if the original values of sourceArray were preserved in a temporary location before destinationArray is overwritten.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx

Comment: But is it still the fastest possible solution?

Comment: Take reflector and check for yourself ;)

Comment: @LukaHorvat Marked your q as dupe because there are very good measurements in the answers of the dupe. `Buffer.BlockCopy` looks to be marginally faster.

Comment: Buffer.BlockCopy() is definitely faster in all the tests I've thrown at it.

Comment: @usr Hopefully `memcpy()` on Windows behaves identically to `memmove()`, then.