# Save and load initial state of an array (int[,])

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to save the state of an array so I can load it later in it's initial state. But I don't know how to make them separate instances, and not to reference each other. Here's some sample code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] first = new int[5, 5];
    int[,] second = first;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            first[i, j] = i * j;
        }
    }

    first[0, 0] = 10000;
    first = second;
    Console.WriteLine(first[0, 0]); //10000
}
```

Comment: So... you are wanting to allocate a *copy* of `first` and assign it to `second`?

Comment: So you want to make copy of the first one?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. I wan't to make some changes to first, and then revert them on restart command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[,] second = first;
```

Means that the second array is a reference to first, they are the same object. You need to create a new array instance. You mention that you want to save the state of the array for later use and for this, you have to copy your original array like so:

```
int[,] first = new int[5, 5];
int[,] second = new int[5, 5];
Array.Copy(first, second, first.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a separate instance, you need to instantiate it:

```
int[,] second = new int[5, 5];
```

Many ways of copying an array can be found here: [Any faster way of copying arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099604/any-faster-way-of-copying-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

```
first = second
```

Only copies the reference. You need to copy the elements one by one, just like the way you populate the first array.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shallow copy with [Array.Clone()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: To use this you'll need a cast, e.g. `int[,] second = (int[,])first.Clone()`.