# How to skip first few elements from array?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, optimization, memory-management

I have an array with total 5000 elements and at one functionality, I only need last 3000 elements only to proceed further.

for that I have tried following solution.

```
//skipping first 2000 elements
list = list.Skip(5000 - 3000).ToArray();
```

This solution is actually giving me desired solution, but when I ran profiler on my code, It is showing huge amount memory allocation on this line.

I have to use Array only due to carried on legacy. and very frequent `ToArray()` doesn't seem to be good for performance.

there is also possible solution,

```
//reversing whole list
Array.Reverse(list);
//restricting size of an array to 3000,
//so first (as reversed the list, they are last 3000 elements) 
Array.Resize(ref list, 3000);
//again reversing list to make it proper order
Array.Reverse(list);
```

but this is even worse in time complexity.

Is there any better solution for this, which doesn't need casting from List to Array ?

Comment: Do you *have* to have those elements in an array rather than just as an `IEnumerable<T>`? Does `ArraySegment` help? It's hard to help when we don't know what you're trying to do with the rest...

Comment: What is `list`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes sir, I know I should have them on `IEnumerable` but decision to make this change is not in my hand. So I have to have it in Array only! And I don't have any specific requirement with resultant array. I'll iterate through it to read the elements.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It is Array of integer.

Comment: If you are comfortable with `unsafe` code, you could use [one of these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099604/any-faster-way-of-copying-arrays-in-c) methods, though his benchmarking doesn't show much difference to `Array.Copy` as far as performance goes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you absolutely *have* to use an array, then `Array.Copy` is probably your friend:

```
int[] smallerArray = new int[array.Length - 2000];
Array.Copy(array, 2000, smallerArray, 0, smallerArray.Length);
```

I'd expect that to be a bit more efficient than using `Take` followed by `ToArray`.

Answer (score 1):

If `list` is a `List<>` you can use [`List.GetRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int lastN = 3000;
var sublist = list.GetRange(list.Count - lastN, lastN);
var array = sublist.ToArray();
```

This is more efficient because  `List.ToArray` uses `Array.Copy`.

---

If `list` is an `int[]` as commented it's even more efficient:

```
int lastN = 3000;
int[] result = new int[lastN];
Array.Copy(list, list.Length - lastN, result, 0, lastN);
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use Skip(Provide number which you want to exclude).ToArray();

Comment: It is mentioned in question. I have tried this before. yes it works but I m asking for better solution.