# Sending data from android to computer over hosted network

Tags: c#, android, sockets, xamarin.android

I've been trying to send data from an android device to a computer by hosting a virtual network on the computer and connecting the android device to it (basically sending data over WLAN).

However, upon debugging the android app it always throws the following exception:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Network subsystem is down.
```

Android App Code Snippet:

```
namespace TestWifiApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestWifiApp", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        string bssid = "00:18:39:12:2b:e9";
        const string ssid = "TEST";
        const string password = "123456abc";
        const string kioskIp = "192.168.137.11";
        const int kioskPort = 2201;
        void sendData(string ntlId)
        {
            try {
                System.Net.Sockets.Socket soc = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp);
                System.Net.IPAddress ipAdd = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(kioskIp);
                System.Net.IPEndPoint ep = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(ipAdd, kioskPort);
                soc.Connect(ep);
                byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ntlId);
                soc.Send(data);
                soc.Disconnect(false);
                soc.Close();
                Log.Debug("TEST", "Data sent");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Debug("TEST",ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Server Code:

```
        class Program
    {
        const int PORT_NO = 2201;
        static Socket serverSocket;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
            Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT_NO));
            serverSocket.Listen(4); //the maximum pending client, define as you wish
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), null);
            string result = "";
            do
            {
                result = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (result.ToLower().Trim() != "exit");
        }

        private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
        private static byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; //buffer size is limited to BUFFER_SIZE per message
        private static void acceptCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        { //if the buffer is old, then there might already be something there...
            Socket socket = null;
            try
            {
                socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(result); // The objectDisposedException will come here... thus, it is to be expected!
                                                         //Do something as you see it needs on client acceptance
                socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket);
                serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), null); //to receive another client
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { // this exception will happen when "this" is be disposed...        
              //Do something here             
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        const int MAX_RECEIVE_ATTEMPT = 10;
        static int receiveAttempt = 0; //this is not fool proof, obviously, since actually you must have multiple of this for multiple clients, but for the sake of simplicity I put this
        private static void receiveCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            Socket socket = null;
            try
            {
                socket = (Socket)result.AsyncState; //this is to get the sender
                if (socket.Connected)
                { //simple checking
                    int received = socket.EndReceive(result);
                    if (received > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] data = new byte[received]; //the data is in the byte[] format, not string!
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, data, 0, data.Length); //There are several way to do this according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099604/any-faster-way-of-copying-arrays-in-c in general, System.Buffer.memcpyimpl is the fastest
                                                                           //DO SOMETHING ON THE DATA int byte[]!! Yihaa!!
                        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)); //Here I just print it, but you need to do something else                     

                        //Message retrieval part
                        //Suppose you only want to declare that you receive data from a client to that client
                        string msg = "I receive your message on: " + DateTime.Now;
                        socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg)); //Note that you actually send data in byte[]
                        Console.WriteLine("I sent this message to the client: " + msg);

                        receiveAttempt = 0; //reset receive attempt
                        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket); //repeat beginReceive
                    }
                    else if (receiveAttempt < MAX_RECEIVE_ATTEMPT)
                    { //fail but not exceeding max attempt, repeats
                        ++receiveAttempt; //increase receive attempt;
                        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket); //repeat beginReceive
                    }
                    else
                    { //completely fails!
                        Console.WriteLine("receiveCallback fails!"); //don't repeat beginReceive
                        receiveAttempt = 0; //reset this for the next connection
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { // this exception will happen when "this" is be disposed...
                Console.WriteLine("receiveCallback fails with exception! " + e.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
```

I've tried connecting another computer to the hosted network and sending data to that computer, but the same exception is thrown.

Comment: `to send data from an android device to a computer by hosting a virtual network on the computer and connecting the android device to it `. That will not do. You cant just send. You need a sender and a receiver. At least a server and a client. You are not even mentioning them.

Comment: @greenapps the device that is hosting the virtual network serves as a "server" and the android device as a "client". I didn't want to overcomplicate it with services so I just want to know how to do it with sockets

Comment: If you want to do 'it' with sockets then you need to use them in a server application and a client application. Just talking about a server device and client device makes no sense. You have to program two apps which run on a device each.