# How to copy from byte[] to new byte[] with some changed element item?

Tags: c#, arrays, copy, byte

I have `byte[]` like this, the length of `byte[]` is `16`, and I want to change some value of an item and add this to a new `byte[]`. For example, the value of `byte[7]` is `13`, I want to change this value with a new value. After that, add into a new byte, the value of `byte[7]` will be changed plus one more unit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Call Array.Copy and then change the bytes to be changed in a next step?

Comment: So, not look like this , copy to another byte[] but some changed element in array @Renat

Comment: @Ralf . Are you draff detail with it.

Comment: Why can't you copy the array and then change the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform the operations the other way round. First copy then change the value in the copied data. This way the original will stay unchanged.

Efficient:

```cs
var original = new byte[]{1,2,3};
var result = new byte[original.Length];

Array.Copy(original, result, original.Length); //first make a copy
result[2] = 42; //then set your new value
//result is now [1, 2, 42]
```

Simple with LINQ:

```cs
//do not forget using System.Linq;
var original = new byte[]{1,2,3};

var result = original.ToArray(); //first copy
result[2] = 42; //then set your new value
//result is now [1, 2, 42]
```

For small data there will be no difference in performance. For large arrays the direct copy should perform a bit better. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099604/any-faster-way-of-copying-arrays-in-c) for further alternatives regarding the copy part.